# How to skip an empty LIKE operator in a multiple LIKE query?

Tags: mysql

I notice my query doesn't behave correctly if one of the like variables is empty:

```
SELECT name 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  name LIKE '%a%' 
AND     color LIKE '%A%' 
AND     city LIKE '%b%' 
AND     country LIKE '%B%' 
AND     sport LIKE '%c%' 
AND     hobby LIKE '%C%'
```

Now when a and A are not empty it works but when a, A and c are not empty the c part is not excuted so it seems?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the record which you think should match but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to do a filter where you only check the value if the filter value is non-null.  In this case, check for nullity in the variable as an alternative condition.

```
select name
from employee
where (@a is null or name like '%' + @a + '%')
   and (@b is null or color like '%' + @b + '%')
   ...
```

Comment: hmm, it returns errors i am using PHP
`
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee
  WHERE ".$a." is null or name LIKE '%".$a."%'
  AND ".$b." is null or color LIKE '%".$b."%'
  AND ".$c." is null or city LIKE '%".$c."%'
`
error reads something like 
the right syntax to use near 'is null

Comment: If you're constructing the query in PHP just check if the variable is empty and don't append the portion that checks it.  That is, build up the query string incrementally only including the relevant bits.  From your question I assumed you meant SQL variables and that the query was being performed in a stored procedure.  My code example is for the SQL to go in the stored proc.

Comment: tx, i have come up with 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee 
   WHERE ('".$a."' is null or name LIKE '%".$a."%')
   AND ('".$b."' is null or city LIKE '%".$b."%')
   etc....
   "
But your suggestion to use empty seems much more elegant, i am going to try it out

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IF()` function....

```
SELECT name 
  FROM employee 
 WHERE ( IF(LENGTH('%a') > 0, name LIKE '%a%' , 0)
    OR IF(LENGTH('%A') > 0, color LIKE '%A%', 0)
    OR IF(LENGTH('%b') > 0, city LIKE '%b%' , 0)
    OR IF(LENGTH('%B') > 0, country LIKE '%B%', 0) 
    OR IF(LENGTH('%c') > 0, sport LIKE '%c%' , 0)
    OR IF(LENGTH('%C') > 0, hobby LIKE '%C%' , 0) 
       )
```

The where clause of a sql query is looking for a `true/false` result from the `AND/OR` logic.  Thus you can return an expression to be TESTed, or the result of a test, or a raw hard `true/false` value from the  `IF()` function.